# Duplicate rows with spaces:

Tags: oracle

I have a dataset as below:

```
SELECT '  1234 ' ID,NULL TAG,' AB' CODE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL 
SELECT '453' ID,'GEN' TAG,'AB' CODE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '1234' ID,NULL TAG,' AB' CODE FROM DUAL)
```

I am trying to get duplicates  with the below query. The output should be row 1 and 3 but i get only one row as trimmed output of 1 or 3.

```
SELECT TRIM(ID),TRIM(TAG),TRIM(CODE) FROM 
(SELECT '  1234 ' ID,NULL TAG,' AB' CODE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL 
SELECT '453' ID,'GEN' TAG,'AB' CODE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '1234' ID,NULL TAG,' AB' CODE FROM DUAL)
WHERE (TRIM(ID),TRIM(TAG),TRIM(CODE)) IN 
(
SELECT TRIM(ID),TRIM(TAG),TRIM(CODE) FROM
(SELECT '  1234 ' ID,NULL TAG,' AB' CODE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL 
SELECT '453' ID,'GEN' TAG,'AB' CODE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '1234' ID,NULL TAG,' AB' CODE FROM DUAL)
GROUP BY TRIM(ID),TRIM(TAG),TRIM(CODE)
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this and it returned rows 1 and 3:

```
SELECT TRIM(ID),TRIM(TAG),TRIM(CODE) 
FROM 
(
    SELECT '  1234 ' ID,NULL TAG,' AB' CODE FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '453' ID,'GEN' TAG,'AB' CODE FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1234' ID,NULL TAG,' AB' CODE FROM DUAL
)
WHERE TRIM(ID) IN 
(
    SELECT TRIM(ID)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT '  1234 ' ID,NULL TAG,' AB' CODE FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '453' ID,'GEN' TAG,'AB' CODE FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '1234' ID,NULL TAG,' AB' CODE FROM DUAL
    )
   GROUP BY TRIM(ID),TRIM(TAG),TRIM(CODE)
   HAVING COUNT(*) >1
)
```

I changed your `WHERE` to reference only the `TRIM(ID)` instead of all 3 values.

**Edit #1**, part of the problem is you are comparing `null` to `null` which you cannot do.  So you can do a `null` check on the columns and if it is `null` then replace it.  I wrapped the `null` columns with `nvl(null, 'na')` so then it had a value to compare:

```
SELECT TRIM(ID) id,TRIM(TAG) tag,TRIM(CODE) code 
FROM 
(
    SELECT '  1234 ' ID, nvl(null, 'na') TAG,' AB' CODE FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '453' ID,'GEN' TAG,'AB' CODE FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '  1234 ' ID,nvl(null, 'na') TAG,' AB' CODE FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '  1234 ' ID,nvl(null, 'na') TAG,' AC' CODE FROM DUAL
)
WHERE (TRIM(ID),TRIM(TAG),TRIM(CODE)) IN 
(
    SELECT TRIM(ID),TRIM(TAG),TRIM(CODE) 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT '  1234 ' ID,nvl(null, 'na') TAG,' AB' CODE FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '453' ID,'GEN' TAG,'AB' CODE FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '  1234 ' ID,nvl(null, 'na') TAG,' AB' CODE FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '  1234 ' ID,nvl(null, 'na') TAG,' AC' CODE FROM DUAL
    )
   GROUP BY TRIM(ID), TRIM(CODE), TRIM(TAG)
   HAVING COUNT(*) >1
)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7b0d/7)

Comment: Thanks for responding....Suppose if i add an extra row to the actual dataset like SELECT ' 1234 ' ID,NULL TAG,' AC' CODE FROM DUAL..........i dont want to see this as a duplicate. In this case your idea will not survive.

Comment: if that is the case, then what would you want the result to be?

Comment: Result should be same as said earlier

Comment: @user1616243 please see my edit.  The issue is you are comparing `null` to `null` which returns nothing.  So you should to a `null` check on the columns and replace it with an value.

Comment: This works ..thanks..I also converted that to a join and it is working fine too

Comment: @user1616243 happy to help, if it works then be sure to accept the answer for future users via the checkmark on the left.